Custom Url Link not working in the context of other application
I have set up a customURL scheme for an application in Ubuntu. The association works fine when I try to launch the link either using xdg-open command or when pasting the link in the browser. However, the link does not work in the context of other application i.e when I paste the link in some text or mail application, the link is not clickable. I have observed that If I paste an http/s link, it is clickable. I wanted to know what needs to be done in order to make the link clickable so that I m able to launch the application?
Below is the entry in the desktop file to create the link association. Now I am able to use myapp://
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Application
Exec=myapp %U
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/myapp;

